# How can I make a property "Write Once Read Many" in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, properties, set, readonly

What is the best way to make a class property "Write Once, Read Many" such that you can only set the property once?

I know that I could pass all the properties in the constructor and make them ReadOnly, but in cases with a lot of properties I don't want a constructor that has 20+ arguments.

Also, I realize I can "roll my own" setters, but having to do that for every property seems like a bunch of redundant coding.

Is there a clean way to do this in VB 2008 .NET 3.5?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079292/should-i-use-set-once-variables/1079316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Write Once Property is never "clean".

I'd recommend to create a builder/factory class to avoid the 20 param CTor. 
(Yes, I know it is quite some typing)

Similar discussion here: 
[Should I use set once variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079292/should-i-use-set-once-variables/1079316#1079316)

[edit] Furthermore, even if you insist I don't see another option than rolling your own setters, which is a lot of typing, too.

Comment: Thanks.  The post you linked explains a lot, and I agree with your "Least surprises" principle.  Using a builder may be the best solution.

Comment: Write-once properties with an exposed setters are not clean, but such properties combined with a `TrySet` method that uses `CompareExchange` can have useful thread-safety characteristics.  For example, in a linked-list queue implementation, a given item's "next" pointer will either be `null` (for the last item), or point to another item.  Code that wants to append to the queue may try to write to the `next` pointer of the last item; if it fails, it must follow `next` pointers until it finds the new last item, and try again.

Comment: @supercat: agreed, but then the setter should be a separate method (like TrySet), not a proeprty setter. So I'd argue "tha's not really a write-once property".

Comment: @peterchen: I would see no reason the thing shouldn't be exposed for reading as a property, and could thus be described as a property.  I don't know of any non-clunky terminology to describe a read-only property whose value can be altered via a method which is exposed at the same level, and whose sole purpose is to alter the property in question.  Syntactically, it's a "read-only" property, but that term usually implies that the object exposing the property provides no way to alter it (even if it could change via other means).

Comment: @peterchen: One could call the property "change once", though the term "change" would imply that the property could have an arbitrary value before the change.  "Set once" might be a little better than "write once", except the term "set" is very strongly associated with a "property setter".  The means by which the property can change, however, is of far less importance than the fact that if it holds a reference to something, it will always refer to that same thing.  Consider, for example, code which wants a read-only snapshot of a queue implemented as described above.

Comment: @peterchen: The consumer won't care about the means that would be used to change the `next` link; what the consumer would care about is that if it captures the number of items that are in the queue at some point in time, along with a link to the first such item, no future changes that may occur to the queue will alter the sequence of items encapsulated by the captured information.  The `next` link would not be immutable on all of the items in the snapshot, but it would be immutable on all the queue items where the snapshot cared about it.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been almost 3 years, but here's my solution which I think is better:

```
public class Site
{
    private int miID;

    public Site(int iNewID, string sName)
    {
        miID = iNewID;
        Name = sName;
    }
    // The ID property can only be set once in the constructor
    public int ID
    {
        get { return miID; }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should try and explain why you think your solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

The "cleanest" way would be not to do it at all and use auto properties. I fail to see the need for it too. Is it really that important that they can only be written once? If so I would definitely go with a constructor that takes values for all the properties as parameters.

Comment: An example of a property I would use this for is an "ID" property, that is a unique identifier for the class.  It isn't life or death, but it would ensure that the "ID" didn't get changed by other code.

I'm not all that familiar with Auto Properties, other than knowing that they aren't supported in the VB version I'm using.  Is it possible to make them Write Once Read Many?